# Fetch data in a single row (key - value)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have stored user data in different row with same `id` but now i want to fetch them in a single row if `id` is same like below.

I have a database like this in mysql

```
id  -   data_id      -      name            -    Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       2        -      your-name       -     Bilal
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       2        -      your-email      -     bilal@gmail.com
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       2        -      your-city       -     Toronto
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       3        -      your-name       -     Hassan
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       3        -      your-email      -     hassan@gmail.com
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   -       3        -      your-city       -     Toronto
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i want to fetch record in below way

```
Data_id     -   Name             Email           -           City
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   -       Bilal         bilal@gmail.com              Toronto
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3   -       Hassan        hassan@gmail.com             Toronto
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anyone can please help how to get the same id-data into one row and showing in 2nd table

Answer (score 0):

All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are instances of the [**`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`**](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) object, including results retrieved via the get method or accessed via a relationship.

The `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class provides a fluent, convenient wrapper for working with arrays of data.

```
$result = $data->groupBy('data_id')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $return = $item->pluck('value', 'name');
    $return->put('data_id', $key);

    return $return;
});

dd($result);
```

---

## Explanation

#### [`grupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-groupby)

The `groupBy` method groups the collection's items by a given key :

```
$result = $data->groupBy('data_id');
```

**Result**

```
array:2 [
  2 => array:3 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 2
      "name" => "your-name"
      "value" => "Bilal"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 2
      "name" => "your-email"
      "value" => "bilal@gmail.com"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 2
      "name" => "your-city"
      "value" => "Toronto"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 3
      "name" => "your-name"
      "value" => "Hassan"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 3
      "name" => "your-email"
      "value" => "hassan@gmail.com"
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "id" => 1
      "data_id" => 3
      "name" => "your-city"
      "value" => "Toronto"
    ]
  ]
]
```

#### [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-map)

The `map` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items:

```
$result = $data->groupBy('data_id')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    // to-do
});
```

#### [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck)

The `pluck` method retrieves all of the values for a given key :

```
$result = $data->groupBy('data_id')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->pluck('value', 'name');
});
```

**Result**

```
array:2 [
  2 => array:3 [
    "your-name" => "Bilal"
    "your-email" => "bilal@gmail.com"
    "your-city" => "Toronto"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "your-name" => "Hassan"
    "your-email" => "hassan@gmail.com"
    "your-city" => "Toronto"
  ]
]
```

#### [`put()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-put)

The `put` method sets the given key and value in the collection :

```
$result = $data->groupBy('data_id')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $return = $item->pluck('value', 'name');
    $return->put('data_id', $key);

    return $return;
});
```

**Result**

```
array:2 [
  2 => array:4 [
    "your-name" => "Bilal"
    "your-email" => "bilal@gmail.com"
    "your-city" => "Toronto"
    "data_id" => 2
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "your-name" => "Hassan"
    "your-email" => "hassan@gmail.com"
    "your-city" => "Toronto"
    "data_id" => 3
  ]
]
```